# Give the following percentage to actions: 65%, 30%, 4%, 1%

Tags: python

I was asked to work at a matchmaking logic and i need to give the following percentage to my code(65%, 30%, 4%, 1%), I just want to check if it's the best implementation, or if you guys have any other ideas:

```
random_session = await create_random_session(
    connection, 'group', session_size=4, random_value = "case1", "case2", "case3", "case4",
        )
    for for random_value in random_session:
                if random.randint(0, 100) < 65:
                    random_value = "case1"
                        continue
            else:
                random.randint(0, 100) < 30:
                    random_value = "case2"
                        continue
            else:
                random.randint(0, 100) < 4:
                    random_value = "case3"
                        continue
            else:
                random.randint(0, 100) < 1:
                    random_value = "case4"
                        continue
```

Comment: To the first two the answer is Yes, but i hope that i could make it faster.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is incorrect. You need to sample once, and then test each of the criteria (i.e., 65%, 30%, 4%, or 1%).

For example, suppose your first test yields a random variate of value 1. The first conditional will fail. Now suppose the second test yields a random variate of 1. Again, your second conditional will fail. Similarly, your third conditional will fail for a random variate of 1. Finally, if the above conditions are met and your fourth test yields a random variate of 1, then your condition will pass and return case4. In other words, as written, to return case 4, requires (equivalently):

```
random.randint(0,100) < 1 and random.randint(0,100) < 1 and random.randint(0,100) < 1 and random.ranint(0,100) < 1
```

Similar problems exist for case2 and case 3

Comment: Yeah, you're right. As a matter of fact i've copy-pasted the wrong code. So thank you.

Comment: Even if the thread is kind of old, that's how i've managed to give the described percentage:                                                                                  def get_give_random_percentage(case_1_percentage = 65,
                    case_2_percentage = 30, case_3_percentage = 4, 
                    case_4_percentage = 1):
    value = ['case1'] * case_1_percentage +['case2'] * \
                case_2_percentage + ['case3'] * \
                case_3_percentage + \
                ['case4'] * case_4_percentage
                
    return random.choice(value)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating new random int for each case it might happen that none of them are true and then random value will be undefiend. Create only one random integer and then compare that for all the cases to prevent this.

Also assignment to the loop variable does not work like this.

```
x=[0,0,0,0]
for i in x:
    i=3
    print x
```

gives you:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and

```
x=[0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i]=3
    print x
```

gives you

```
[3, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 3, 0, 0]
[3, 3, 3, 0]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

I also think you want to use `continue` instead of `break`so you go through all the items in `random_session`